# Reactjs create multiple object array declaration

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, object

Below is my coding when I am trying to get the coordinates of the polygon from react-google-maps:

```
const coords = { lat:{}, lng:{} }

 getCoordinates: () => (polygon) => {
  const paths = polygon.getPath()
  const coor = paths.b

  {coor.map(function(coor, i){
    coords.lat= coor.lat()
    coords.lng= coor.lng()
  })}
  return console.log(coords)
}
```

I'm trying to get the object array for "coords"like below:

```
coords = [
  { lat: 3.1323583333745533, lng: 101.62676453590393 },
  { lat: 3.1318226928949433, lng: 101.62672162055969 },
  { lat: 3.131753059612469, lng: 101.6274243593216 }
]
```

But using the code will give me this:

```
coords = { 
  lat: 3.131753059612469, 
  lng: 101.6274243593216 
}
```

which is the last coordinates out of the three.

How do I can get all three coordinates under "coords"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to push to an array instead of object, hope it helps!

```
let coords = [];

getCoordinates: () => (polygon) => {
    const paths = polygon.getPath();
    const coor  = paths.b;

    coor.forEach((c) => {
        coords.push({
            lat: c.lat(),
            lng: c.lng()
        });
    });

    return console.log(coords);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `map` together with `push`. If you want to `push` to an array explicitly, use a normal `for (let c of coor)` loop instead

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong method, I am just modifying the code without checking the function used, updated the code to `forEach` instead

Comment: Thanks, better, though I still dislike the `forEach` + `push` combination when one could just use `map` :-P

Comment: Got it, I am overusing `forEach` recently so can't think of using `map`, will try to use more `map` and `filter` etc in the future =)

Comment: I recommend to *never* use `forEach`. For side effects (i.e. when you don't need a result value), use `for … of`. This also allows to use things like `yield`, `await`, `return`, `break` and `continue` in the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

This code is *really* confused. You seem to be looking for

```
function getCoordinates(polygon) {
  const paths = polygon.getPath()
  const coords = paths.b.map(coor => ({
    lat: coor.lat(),
    lng: coor.lng()
  }));
  return coords;
}

console.log(getCoordinates(…));
```